# Why integration testing in jest is too slow when I am testing for first time, but testing second time is fast in ubuntu, in mac O.S there is no issue

Tags: jestjs, integration-testing, ubuntu-16.04, ts-jest

**Running First time - 1480 seconds**

PASS  tests/integration/CompanyProductIntegration.test.ts (1480.081 s)
✓ Find company products (63 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1480.125 s
Ran all test suites matching /tests/integration/CompanyProductIntegration.test.ts/i.

**Running this test second time - 42.5 seconds**

PASS  tests/integration/CompanyProductIntegration.test.ts (42.551 s)
✓ Find company products (52 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        42.588 s, estimated 1481 s
Ran all test suites matching /tests/integration/CompanyProductIntegration.test.ts/i.

*But in mac O.S this issue is not there. Can anybody help me out??*